# req.session.loggedin is undefined

Tags: express, express-session

yall i have a problem while using express-session addon. No matter what I do it doesn't seem to recognize the existence of session.loggedin if I don't directly declare it. Any help would be appreciated!

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
const PORT = 9000;
const session = require("express-session");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set("trust proxy", 1);
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "dupa",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: { secure: false }, // ustaw na true, jeśli jesteś na https
  })
);


app.post("/api/login", (req, res) => {
  var { username, password } = req.body;

  if (username === "admin" && password === "admin") {
    req.session.loggedin = true;
    console.log(req.session.loggedin); //this shows TRUE
    req.session.save();
    res.send("Login successful");
  } else {
    res.send("Invalid credentials");
  }
});

app.get("/api/check", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.session.loggedin); //This shows UNDEFINED
  if (req.session.loggedin) {
    res.send(true);
  } else {
    res.send(false);
  }
});



app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

I tried restarting, reinstalling changing setting in session declaration